# get id from comma separated column from database in codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i am trying to get values from a comma seaparated field in my database column, my column looks like this:

[image]

i did the following code in my mode:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where("pc", $mid);
$this->db->where_in("category", $lid);

$this->db->from('product');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
return $result;
```

however this doesnt give the result correctly, can anyone please tell what is wrong in here, thanks in advance

Comment: The best solution here would be to refactor the database design to use a relational database properly [See this for why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Your code is  not getting a single id from a comma  delimited fields anywhere in this code. Do you mean you are trying to search for `2` in a column that contains `2,3`

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, i am trying to search 2 in a column that contains 2,3

Comment: As mentioned above, the root cause of this is your poor database design. Even if you solve this particular scenario, it will continue to cause you other problems. You should strongly consider normalising it properly.

Comment: One of the linked answers suggests to use `FIND_IN_SET()` but you should know that this blocks the use of an index, so a query that searches that way will have to do a table-scan, and suffer poor performance.